# Problem with Podman Systemd with changing PIDFile Location

Tags: docker, centos, containers, systemd, podman

I've got multiple systemd files starting different containers. I wanted to add dependency with `After=` for a clean startups. So i needed to configure the systemd with the PIDFile to track the status of the container.
Using `podman generate systemd <name>` outputs something like this:

`/tmp/run-1002/overlay-containers/7a1b971c5cdacafca54555837e0ccd4d50546e61fe4882c0b29215462e34da11/userdata/conmon.pid`

My problem is now that im doing `podman rm keycloak` and `podman run --name keycloak ..` in my `ExecStart=` Start-scripts. So i got always a different path for the PID File because the PIDFIle Path is unfortunately only with the hashname. I didnt manage to configure the systemd to use a dynamic PID somehow.

Can someone give me a hint how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the PID-File parameter of the podman  command.

podman run --conmon-pidfile=/opt/run/myPID.pid ...

and in the systemd file

PIDFile=/opt/run/myPID.pid